# C# Objects to relational database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I held a course for Databases and SQL in SQL server.

Now I have a course about OOAD-design with UML.

Is there a way that I can make a person-klass and save the object directly down to a table in SQL Server and get it back into an object.

The important thing is that the students can practice SQL but also se how you can use an application för saving to a database and get it back.

So I want them to make the tables in the database first.

Comment: That is called an Object Relational Mapper (ORM), of which there are dozens. To write your own basic one as an academic exercise is not that difficult, but in this forum, you need to try, and ask specific questions about problems with  your code.

Comment: Make Database. Make Object. Map Object to Database. Done. Anything more is going to require some code on your part

Comment: Well first I would not recommend teaching something you don't understand. It will just give people bad info on ORMs and that's how you get "Entity Framework is slow" and stuff like that.

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL  Server.  You can manually built a database using the explorer in SSMS.  You can build Tables and enter data.  Then read back results ina c# application.

Comment: Well , the problem isn't the database. We have been using SSMS so that part is no problem.

I have been using ADO in the past but had an idea of showing how to save objects to a relational database as an simple exercise. I know a little about Entity Framework. But that creates the tables automaticly if I understand it right.

Maybe better to not show that part as I doesn't fully understand it.

Well, perhaps the wrong forum.